# Active Directory in an Azure VM - just for VM identies?

Tags: azure, active-directory

Is it sensible to set up Active Directory in Azure, purely for managing identities in the virtual environment? (*update*: identities as in log on to the vm not our software). We don't currently have an on-site AD installation. Should we be looking at integrating our on-site systems with this AD controller too?

Are there any alternatives to just installing it in a VM following the [MSDN instructions here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/)? (mainly in terms of scope for making bad decisions during initial configuration as someone with no real sysadmin or AD experience!)

Answer (score 0):

There is a preview currently running which sounds like a better fit for your purposes.  Whether you integrate with your on-prem AD is your call of course.  To do so you can use ADFS to ACS to link through from your Azure app.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/identity/

Comment: Steve just to clarify, when I say identities these are log ons to the server themselves for admin purposes and process isolation rather than managing identity on our web apps. As far as I've seen the preview only addresses that angle? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry James, my misunderstanding.